# I have google apps enabled add-on domain doesn't get emails

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have Google apps enabled for 2 domains when I try to send emails via SMTP or Email API to these domains the primary domain receives email whereas the **add-on domain doesn't get emails**.

Here is my sample code:

```
$to      = 'hello@xyz.com';

$subject = 'the subject';

$message = 'hello testing';

$headers = 'From: care@xyz.com' . "\r\n" .

'Reply-To: hello@xyz.com' . "\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers));
```

Comment: I think deepak you should contact to your hosting service provider. Code seems fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check you server is configurations done as per Googles Settings if your want to send mail through Google servers?

[Add MX entries for Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en)

Otherwise you need to check the possibilities of your server to send email.

[Domain & Server capability Checking](http://www.intodns.com/) , [SMTP settings](http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx)

**I think the better option for SMTP email integration using php [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php) and you can use your email settings or even using GMail to send email to your clients and easy to configure without knowing your domain or server configurations**